# Where to download SCOM 2007 R2?

Tags: scom

I'm browsing the MSDN subscriber downloads and they only have up to SCOM 2007 SP1.  Searching Microsoft downloads has the R2 evaluation edition, but that's not what I need.

The R2 release has been available for a least the last month, so where should I be able to find it?

Comment: MVLS now has SCOM 2007 R2 available for download.  MSDN subscriber download is still no-show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you picked the right day...

> General Availability of the product will be 1st July 2009, at which point new and existing customers will be able to obtain the bits from their respective customer download centers, such as MVLS.

[via technet](http://blogs.technet.com/momteam/archive/2009/05/22/system-center-operations-manager-2007-r2-rtm.aspx)

My guess is it'll appear at some point today.

Comment: Hmm, so I wonder why the trial has been available since May.  I'll remain patient.